# unable to save excel file with vba:

Tags: excel, vba, save

I have a vba code that contain a base64 encoded GIF.

When I copy paste the encoded base64 gif from notepad to my sub process in vba like this:

```
imgStr = imgStr & "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlh4AHwAPdrAEksR5CSk5KUlpSVl5aYmpibnJudnZ6fn653la6usLS0tba2tre4uLm5ubu6uru6vb6+vsXFxs/MzdDT0tnZ2d7d3ebn5+vq6+/x8fHx8fj5+f39/f7+/jsrRkEVPEMaQENxez8MNUEROUETO0EUO0ITOkwfRUFLWERNW1JfaVmfqa2ztESVm0AROTZNWj6LkS9pcqOenmiUmDl9gmpjdotlh"
imgStr = imgStr & "pmdnTV3fUGSl0COlECPlUCQljqLkkOPlTmAhz+LklhJWUGPk5yYnmU9XxsjKC41PDM0NjQ9RUdSXkmgpk18iVBSVGpsbnAQWXodU4OEip0hUJ1CdKAfPaanqLFvgLMUH7QcMLcZJbtXc72SsL9TS8AyOcOzushVXNCfrNF5gN3d3d7x8d+yud/f3+Pj4+34+PLy8vPx8/Tz8/X19fb19SAmLCInLSIpLyQoLiUrMS".....
```

then I can unable to save it with the following error: "Errors were dectected saving....".

I do have the felling it only comes with the string is copy/paste from notepad, but I really do not understand what happen.

Is there something that already experienced this issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does it end up exceeding 32,767 characters?

Comment: Yes it does, it reaches 197 000 char. But the string is located in a sub process not inside a cell. My code is working well, the problem only appears when I need to save..

Comment: You are going to have to find a different method then. Think about why you need to save the image as a base64 string. There are limits you cannot exceed. Maybe save the image to a file instead, and then store the path/filename to the image. Hard to really know what to recommend without knowing your entire process. Just know that it's not going to work the way you want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a form to have a gif animation during the execution of my script:

```
<HTML><BODY style='border-style:none;'><div style='align:center'><img alt='' src='" & imgStr & "' /></div></BODY></HTML>"
```

where imgStr is my encoded 64 gif. But I guess it is too big..